# NPC AI constructing map of obstacles without grid

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, 2d-games

For some research purpose I've build a small tanks game where you have 1 tank controlled by a player and one or more NPC tanks.

Now I want these NPC tanks to navigate through a field which they have no knowledge of. They can detect obstacles if they are in a certain range. If they detect those obstacles they should save them in a certain data construct that's easy to query. So that they can take them in account when moving.

Now here is where I'm stuck : if my field would be a grid it would be quite easy for me, I would just save which tiles/nodes the obstacle is on.

But I haven't really worked with a grid, my tanks just move forward a few pixels depending on their speed, so a tank can be located on any pixel combination, as well as the obstacles.

Now how would I handle this? Collision detection is out of scope. 
Am I forced to use some kind of grid or waypoints ?

Comment: the screen pixels *do* form a grid. Why not use it?

Comment: That makes the grid way too large. Path finding will be almost impossible.

Comment: unless you have very small paths, you can downscale the grid, and the results will be accurate, no?

Comment: What if I have 2 obstacles next to each other, but one placed 1 pixel higher..

Comment: that would be a small path indeed. How big are the tanks?

Comment: That's customizable with parameters.. (Now I'm testing with 14px width - 20px length )

Comment: then it's probably safe to divide by that size, since the tanks couldn't pass by a path smaller than their size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use a [navigation mesh](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigation_mesh) solution? seems like exactly what you're looking for, a method for representing a domain for ai navigation with arbitrary polygonal obstacles.

github is down at the moment, but according to [this website](http://code.google.com/p/straightedge/) (which is worth checking out, it's an interesting Java implementation), [this project](https://github.com/CBCJVM/python-pathfinding) has a python navigation mesh implementation.

*edit*

Based on your comments below, I think that [a hierarchical representation](http://aigamedev.com/open/review/near-optimal-hierarchical-pathfinding/) is actually closer to the answer you are looking for.  This article links to a paper describing how to abstract the pixel-by-pixel grid (with arbitrary shaped obstacles) into a node-edge graph for increased speed in navigation calculations.  By incorporating this type of hierarchical representation with a dynamic navigation algorithm such as d* (see [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l/11866#11866) for an overview of dynamic navigation algorithms), you should be able to implement a solution to your problem.

Comment: But such a navigation mesh has to be defined before the game starts, in this way the AI can't really discover the map. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's a good point.  The navigation mesh does have to be pre-computed.

Comment: Well this certainly looks interesting, I've +1'ed your answer.